# Use of だった in the middle of a sentence

Tags: grammar

> 西の村では、様々な武装を試してみた結果、一番使いやすかった木槍を正式採用し、それなりに訓練を重ねている。
>
> 一方で東の村は、ほとんど組織**だった**防衛力を準備出来ていない。

Comparing military power between the two villages.

after this sentence it was explained how the leadership of the village fell apart before the invasion by the west village. So one could conclude that *because* the village's organization (or lack there of),  防衛力を準備出来ていない。

But without that further context, could you read 組織だった in that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

組織だった (組織立った) is the past tense form of the verb [組織立つ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%B5%84%E7%B9%94%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4-554349), "to be organized" "to be systematic".